# Qt GUI Application Linux

Tags: linux, qt

My problem is that when I want to create new project in QT Creator, there is no QT Gui Application template (Ubuntu). Is there any solution to get this template ?

Comment: The term you're looking for is *Widgets*, not *GUI*. That's all. This question is essentially a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt Gui is now "Qt Widgets"

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qt5-intro.html#widgets-in-qt-5 since Qt 5.0.

Download from here

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/libqwt6/

Comment: Thank you very much for the response it is really helpful

Comment: If this helped can you accept this as the answer , Thank you :)

Comment: What has Qt widgets got to do with qwt? This answer is wrong. At best, it will pull the widgets module as a dependency, but it's completely unnecessary to install QWT.

Answer (score 2):

I select a Qt Widget application.

[image: Qt widget application selection]

Comment: I think this on mac ?

Comment: @VinayShukla - no this screen shot was not from a Mac.